# Use Swagger 2.0 to describe a single parameter of multiple types

Tags: swagger-2.0

I make some yamls by openapi3.0 as follow:

```
- name: ip
  in: query
  schema:
    type: string
    oneOf:
    - format: ipv4
    - format: ipv6
- name: ipv4
  oneOf:
  - $ref: 'xxx/Ipv4Type'
  - type: array
    items:
      $ref: 'xxx/Ipv4'
```

But for some reason, I must convert it to swagger2.0. How should I translate them up here?

Comment: Is the 2nd parameter (`ipv4`) a parameter or a property in some schema? Its syntax looks like neither and is probably an error.

Comment: It's a parameter, the return value could be object or array, I don't how to describe them